# Where to get the name of the UI Components of Android Application?

Tags: android, ui-design

I am new to Android Application Development. As an Android Developer it is better to have a source, PDF file etc that contains the whole list of UI components of Android application with their names and screenshot.

For example:

**Titlebar:**

[image]

**Navigation Side Menu:**

[image]

Etc.

Before negative marking my question please note that i did lot of search for this purpose and right now i am at the [Material Design](https://material.io/), [tutlane](https://www.tutlane.com/), and android developer [official](https://developer.android.com/guide) website. But the content there is spread and not collected to keep it as a pocket document. Can anyone have a source of such information to share here. Thanks !!!

Comment: You start getting to know these components with time as you spend time developing for Android, and when you start researching more.

Comment: Try codelab example  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/

Comment: You remind me something painful when i started android development before 3 years. I was also looking for the same resource to keep things in mind always but i am failed. It will be better may someone help, i am also waiting for response from any bird here.

Comment: Do you have any resource? Did you arranged then?

Comment: No, but i was using the android developers website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this site about material design. I think big part of views are described and showed there.[material.io](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html)